# normality of residuals in a multiple regression hypothesis not met?

Tags: r, regression, normal-distribution, hypothesis-testing

I am trying a multiple regression on a 25000 observations data base, with 7 independant variables, and one dependant, of course the first thing to do in a regression is to verify the normality of the residuals, in my markdown file a try capturing them then use qqnorm to compare the observations in the DB with the theoritical values if the obs were normally distributed :

```
mod<-lm(moy_exam2~Math+PC+SVT+EI+Ar+Fr+HG,epltn)
e<-mod$residuals
qqnorm(e,epltn=TRUE,ylab="Quantiles observés",xlab="Quantiles théoriques")
```

the dots must be close to aligned , but I get this weird shape,
[image: weired shape]
is this a big problem ? is it suggesting my multiple regression is useless because the normality Hypothesis is not met (bc afward, I run it and the R squared was 0.995)? what can I do to fix it ?
thanks in advance.
PS: I couldn't use Multiple-regression so I tagged linear regression